# Pre-schedule parallel tasks with Intel TBB

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I have multiple batches processed one by one in a serial fashion and each batch's elements are computed in parallel. As I repeat this operation dozens of times, it seems to introduce an little overhead with thread sheduling.

I would like to know if it's possible to set those tasks in advance and then call them during the serial loop. The number of batches or the elements per batch doesn't change over time.

```cpp
// Repeat for N iterations
for (auto n = 0; n < iterations; ++i)
{
    // Serial loop on batches 
    for (auto i = 0; i < BatchCount; ++i)
    {
        // Get current constraint group start index and size
        const auto batchStart = offset[i];
        const auto batchSize  = offset[i + 1] - batchStart;

        // Parallel loop on the batch items
        tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0, batchSize, grainSize),
            [&](const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& range) { 
                for (auto j = range.begin(); j != range.end(); ++j)
                {
                    const auto index = batchStart + j
                    // Call some functions here
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Defining the tasks in advance won't change anything about the thread scheduling overhead, because TBB will still have the same amount of threads in the thread pool. How do observe the thread overhead?

Comment: @MikevanDyke The code runs a lot faster if I compute all the batches in a single parallel loop. Therefore, my guess is that a lot of performance in lost during the thread scheduling.

Comment: FWIW I usually use tbb::pipeline for that pattern

Comment: @WilliamClements Thanks for the advice. I'm not sure how to approach this with tbb::pipeline as I've never used it. Would you be kind enough to share a simple snippet?

Comment: On second thought, if you don't have any computes that would fill out a proper first stage, tbb::pipeline won't help. When you say performance is lost during scheduling ... often that actually means the amount of computation per "task" is too small and gets overwhelmed by thread context switching and the like. Measuring better than guessing.

Comment: What are  the values of `batchSize` and `grainSize`?

Comment: @MikevanDyke batchSize is variable depending on the inputs. grainSize is 128.

Comment: If `batchSize` is large enough, it's hard to tell where the problem lies from the code snippet that you have postet. We might need more information about the functions that are called, if you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For scheduling a TBB task, a rule of thumb is that a task should
execute for at least 1 microsecond or 10,000 processor cycles in
order to mitigate the overheads associated with task creation and
scheduling.

Pre-scheduling the tasks in advance will not help in overcoming the thread
scheduling overhead.

we are assuming a world where the slight additional overhead
of dynamic task scheduling is the most effective at
exposing the parallelism and exploiting it. This assumption has one
fault: if we can program an application to perfectly match the
hardware, without any dynamic adjustments, we may find a few
percentage points gain in performance.

tbb::pipeline has been
deprecated. It was replaced by tbb::parallel_pipeline. For more
information please refer to the below link:
https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/1.0-rev-3/elements/oneTBB/source/algorithms/functions/parallel_pipeline_func.html